# Is there a way to avoid CUDA atomicAdd in my situation?

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, atomic

I'm doing an operation as the figure below.

[image]

Here is my kernel.

As shown in the figure, I make a small matrix using about one million vectors and accumulate it in a large prepared matrix.

I need an idea that can improve performance without exceeding 8Gb of GPU global memory.

How can I avoid atomic operations? I use the GTX1080. Existing kernels take about 250ms.

```
__global__ void buildMatrixKernel(const CostJacobianCT *src, const int num, const int st, const int mw_width, double *A, double *b)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx < num)
    {
        if (src[idx].mask == 1)
        {
            // matrix width
            int cols = 6 * (mw_width + 1);

            // calc position for insert
            int idx0 = (src[idx].fid0 - st);
            if (idx0 == mw_width - 2)
            {
                idx0 = idx0 - 1;
            }
            else if (idx0 == mw_width - 1)
            {
                idx0 = idx0 - 2;
            }

            int idx1 = (src[idx].fid1 - st);
            if (idx1 == mw_width - 2)
            {
                idx1 = idx1 - 1;
            }
            else if (idx1 == mw_width - 1)
            {
                idx1 = idx1 - 2;
            }
            int pos0 = idx0 * 6;
            int pos1 = idx1 * 6;

            // set tempolar matrix
            double _A00[24 * 24];
            double _A11[24 * 24];
            double _A01[24 * 24];
            double _b0[24];
            double _b1[24];
            for (int y = 0; y < 24; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 24; x++)
                {
                    _A00[y * 24 + x] = src[idx].w * src[idx].J0[y] * src[idx].J0[x];
                    _A11[y * 24 + x] = src[idx].w * src[idx].J1[y] * src[idx].J1[x];
                    _A01[y * 24 + x] = src[idx].w * src[idx].J0[y] * src[idx].J1[x];
                }
                _b0[y] = src[idx].w * src[idx].c * src[idx].J0[y];
                _b1[y] = src[idx].w * src[idx].c * src[idx].J1[y];
            }

            // set final matrix
            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++)
                {
                    atomicAdd(&A[(i + pos0) * cols + (j + pos0)], _A00[i * 24 + j]); // 00
                    atomicAdd(&A[(i + pos1) * cols + (j + pos1)], _A11[i * 24 + j]); // 11
                    atomicAdd(&A[(i + pos0) * cols + (j + pos1)], _A01[i * 24 + j]); // 01
                    atomicAdd(&A[(i + pos1) * cols + (j + pos0)], _A01[j * 24 + i]); // 10
                }
                atomicAdd(&b[i + pos0], _b0[i]); // 0
                atomicAdd(&b[i + pos1], _b1[i]); // 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

2019.3.6.
I modified the code below to see some performance improvements.
250ms -> 95ms

```
__global__ void buildMatrixKernel(const CostJacobianCT *src, const int num, const int st, const int mw_width, double *A, double *b)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx < num)
    {
        int src_idx = idx / 576;
        if (src[src_idx].mask == 1)
        {
            int cols = 6 * (mw_width + 1);
            int pos0 = src[src_idx].pos0;
            int pos1 = src[src_idx].pos1;
            double w = src[src_idx].w;
            double c = src[src_idx].c;

            int sub_idx = idx % 576;
            int i = sub_idx / 24;
            int j = sub_idx % 24;

            double J0_i = src[src_idx].J0[i];
            double J0_j = src[src_idx].J0[j];
            double J1_i = src[src_idx].J1[i];
            double J1_j = src[src_idx].J1[j];

            atomicAdd(&A[(i + pos0) * cols + (j + pos0)], w * J0_i * J0_j); // 00
            atomicAdd(&A[(i + pos1) * cols + (j + pos1)], w * J1_i * J1_j); // 11
            atomicAdd(&A[(i + pos0) * cols + (j + pos1)], w * J0_i * J1_j); // 01
            atomicAdd(&A[(i + pos1) * cols + (j + pos0)], w * J1_i * J0_j); // 10

            if (j == 0)
            {
                atomicAdd(&b[i + pos0], w * c * J0_i); // 0
                atomicAdd(&b[i + pos1], w * c * J1_i); // 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not obvious why you need to use  atomic addition in the first place. Are there memory races in the accumulation that need to be serialized ?

Comment: @talonmies yes, a [24x24] small matrix accumulates in multiple locations on the [246x246] matrix and has many overlaps. In other words, the same pos0 or pos1 occur in multiple threads.

Comment: Try temporary matrices per thread with plain +=, then reduce them into A matrix.

Comment: @huseyin Too much memory is required.
sizeof (double) * 246 * 246 * thread_num.
thread_num is about 1,000,000.

Comment: @TaewonKim in your question, you have i and j going from 0 to 23 this needs only 24x24 temporary matrix (`tmp[i][j]+=var;`) then you can reduce all threads temp mat into A matrix using proper indexing with pos0 and pos1 and others. You can even use warp shuffles and a single `__shared__` matrix to do this but this can be trickier(but faster) than simply using matrix-per-thread.

Comment: @huseyin oh.. I see! wow!! thank you very much. I'll try!

Comment: In that case, the only way to avoid atomic operations is to exploit a priori information about the structure of the problem, by using a graph decomposition of the structure of the matrix and running your kernel multiple times

Comment: There might be a way to avoid atomics by assigning each target column to a thread and each target line to a block for example. Then, the logic of building the input data will get more complicated, but no race condition in the end. The overall performance will depend on your input data. It may not result in performance improvement though.